# No match for call using vector

Tags: c++

It seems that i have issue with block[i], how do i resolve this?

```
for(int i=0;i<range.size();i++)
        {
            vector <string> block(i);
        }


for(int i=0; i<range.size();i++)
    {
    int counter=1;

    if(range[counter] == block[i])
    {    
       block[i].push_back(range[counter-1]); <<<<<<<< ERROR: No match for call
       counter++;
    } 
    }
```

Comment: There is no variable called `block` here...

Comment: What are the types of `block, range` ? I guess you are trying to push_back a different type than the type of the template instantiated.

Comment: block and range are vector

Comment: vector of what?  Why did you show us the definitions of `block0`, `block1` and `block2` (which you don't use anywhere in this code) instead of the definitions of `block` and `range`?

Comment: i have vector block0,block1,block2, so in the for loop i want the value to automatically insert the value into block0/block1/block3

Comment: is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

You have no variable called `block`. If you want to index your `block`s, put them in a vector too:

```
vector<vector<string>> blocks (3);
```

> i have vector block0,block1,block2, so in the for loop i want the value to automatically insert the value into block0/block1/block3

That's impossible. Use the solution above.

Comment: Most Vexing Parse doesn't apply here.

Comment: what if the vector was created in another loop?

Comment: @user1745860 suggest you research "variable scope"

Answer (score 0):

If the number of your blocks is a compile-time constant, you may want to consider an array:

```
std::vector<std::string> block[3];             // c++03
std::array<std::vector<std::string>,3> block;  // c++11
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your `block` variables inside the first loop and they disappear after each loop terminates.

You will need to declare you `block` vector outside (before) the first loop, then use `push_back`.

Comment: when i manually change block[i] to block[1] it work perfectly

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can create a vector of vectors, what is needed if you want to index your vectors:

```
vector<vector<string> > vec3(3, std::vector<string>());
```

or

```
std::array<std::vector<std::string>,3> block;  // in case of c++11
```

or

```
vector<vector<string> > blocks (3);
```

Comment: `block0/1/2/` will be copied inside `blocks`. There's no reason to create them. And in C++11 space between `>>` is unnecessary. In your current solution `blocks` will have 6 elements.

Comment: Nobody said it's not; C++11 is the most recent C++ standard and should be assumed by default. And now that I see how you edited your answer, I really want to downvote it again, sadly I can't :/ There's no need whatsoever to use pointers, and now you are leaking memory. This solution is terrible.

Comment: where do you see a leak?

Comment: Now it's ok, but the third one will still have 6 elements :P